# SBT/Play: How to use JavaAppPackaging with PlayScala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

In my build.sbt file I have (among others) a project using Play. I have the sbt native packager building an RPM for it. Unfortunately, it seems to use the `JavaServerAppPackaging` archetype by default as soon as the `PlayScala` plugin is enabled, hence the RPM contains files to deploy under `/etc/default` (probably for config) and `/var/run` (probably for the PID).

Now I want the app to be deployed and run by a normal user (using a local RPM database), not by root, and not as a service.

Is there a way to use `PlayScala` and `JavaAppPackaging` at the same time? I obviously tried `.enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, PlayScala,  SbtWeb)` but it still uses the Server archetype.

Comment: I managed to get the source of the sbt-play plugin and the Play.scala file has `object Play extends AutoPlugin { override def requires = SbtTwirl && SbtJsTask && RoutesCompiler && JavaServerAppPackaging` so that explains the behavior. Is there a simple solution for me to "get rid" of this `JavaServerAppPackaging`? I'm not an expert in sbt...

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Not at the time when I was looking for one, so I finally implemented my own routine to package the RPM. But some time ago I discovered that one can disable a plugin, so something like .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, PlayScala,  SbtWeb).disablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging) might work, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: that didn't worked but yeah I found alternative to achieve the same goal by using some custom mappings. So I was able to remove items, and avoid generation of few things which I did not want.